# How do I use preg_match to do this?

Tags: php, regex

How do I use preg_match to return an array of all substrings that match (:)?

For example if I have a string that is:

```
My name is (:name), my dog's name is (:dogname)
```

I want to use preg_match to return

```
array("name", "dogname");
```

I tried using this expression...

```
preg_match("/\(:(?P<var>\w+)\)/", $string, $temp);
```

But it only returns the first match.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That's what [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) is for. Notice the `_all` suffix.

Comment: Oh!  No wonder it didn't work.  How embarrassing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you want `preg_match_all` (find all matches), not `preg_match` (check if there are any matches at all).

And for the actual regex, the best technique is to search for `(:` and then search for any character except for `)`

```
$string = "My name is (:name), my dog's name is (:dogname)";

$foundMatches = preg_match_all('/\(:([^)]+)\)/', $string, $matches);
$matches = $foundMatches ? $matches[1] : array(); // get all matches for the 1st set of parenthesis. or if there were no matches, just an empty array

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you :)

```
$s = "My name is (:name), my dog's name is (:dogname)";
$preg = '/\(:(.*?)\)/';
echo '<pre>';
preg_match_all($preg, $s, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [preg_match](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> `preg_match()` returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be
>   either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because preg_match() will stop
>   searching after the first match. [`preg_match_all()`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) on the contrary will
>   continue until it reaches the end of subject. `preg_match()` returns
>   `FALSE` if an error occurred.